# httptest.NewRequest issues with query parameters

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm using the GIN framework with a Postgres DB and GORM as an ORM.

One of the routes accepts query parameters. When I search for this in my browser, I get the expected results: an array of json objects. Here is the route:
`/artworks/?limit=10&last_id=1`

However, when I try to test the handler used by that route, I get the following error:
`routes_test.go:184: [ERROR] Unable to unmarshal data to artworks: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []models.Artwork`

The query that the ORM is trying to run in the test function is the folowing:
`SELECT * FROM "artwork_migrate_artwork" WHERE id = ''`

So when I run the request in the browser, it properly pulls the query parameters and then the ORM runs the proper sql query. But when using httptest.NewRequest it seems like the query parameters are not used.

Here is my test function:

```
func TestGetArtworks(t *testing.T) {
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=%s TimeZone=%s", env_var.Host, env_var.User, env_var.Password, env_var.DBname, env_var.Port, env_var.SSLMODE, env_var.TimeZone)
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect to db")
    }

    route := "/artworks/"
    handler := handlers.GetArtwork(db)
    router := setupGetRouter(handler, route)
    writer := httptest.NewRecorder()
    req := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/artworks/?limit=10&last_id=1", nil)
    fmt.Println(req)
    router.ServeHTTP(writer, req)

    assert.Equal(t, 200, writer.Code)

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(writer.Body)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("\u001b[31m[Error] Unable to read writer.Body: %s", err)
    }

    // no body can be unmarshalled
    fmt.Println("Here is the body:", writer.Body.String())

    var artworks []models.Artwork
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &artworks); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("\u001b[31m[ERROR] Unable to unmarshal data to artworks: %s", err)
    }

    assert.Equal(t, 10, len(artworks))
}
```

Here is my route handler:

```
func GetArtworks(db *gorm.DB) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        limit, err := strconv.Atoi(c.Query("limit"))
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        last_id := c.Query("last_id")

        var artworks []models.Artwork
        db.Where("id > ?", last_id).Limit(limit).Find(&artworks)

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, artworks)
    }
}
router.GET("/artworks", han.GetArtworks(db))
```

Here is the model struct:

```
type Artwork struct {
    ID              int       `json:"id"`
    Title           string    `json:"title"`
    Nationality     string    `json:"nationality"`
    Artist_Bio      string    `json:"artist_bio"`
    Desc            string    `json:"desc"`
    Culture         string    `json:"culture"`
    Gender          string    `json:"gender"`
    Nation          string    `json:"nation"`
    Medium          string    `json:"medium"`
    Date_of_Release string    `json:"date_of_release"`
    Image           string    `json:"image"`
    Image_Small     string    `json:"image_small"`
    Last_Modified   time.Time `json:"last_modified"`
    Artist_ID       int       `json:"artist_id"`
    Source_ID       int       `json:"source_id"`
}
```

Comment: I think you could reduce lots of boilerplate to ask that question. If I understand correctly, your code just fails to unmarshal the request data. The error suggests that you expect a list of `Artwork`, i.e. a json structure like `[ {"id": 2, "title": "mytitle", ...]`, but the `request` data holds a signle json object (without the wrapping `[ ]` forming a list).

Comment: The error has nothing at all to do with query parameters. The problem is that you're trying to unmarshal a JSON object (`{...}`) into a Go slice `[]models.Artwork`.

Comment: If I were you, I'd add something like `fmt.Println(string(data))` to your test right before the `json.Unmarshal()` call, and paste the output here so we can see what the response body actually looks like. Based on the error message, the response body most likely is a single JSON object, rather than a JSON array. You need the data to look like this: `[{}, {}]` whereas it probably looks like this: `{}`

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Let me try to clarify the issue. I know that I'm only getting a single object in the test func. When I use a browser, I get an array of objects, as expected. The handler writes a sql query with the query params and properly returns an array of objects when the browser is used.

When I'm using the httptest.NewRequest in my test function however, it fails to write the query properly because it doesn't use the query parameters. Why would the query params be used when sent over the browser but not test?

Thank you again for your responses and for bearing with me!

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. You are using `handler := handlers.GetArtwork(db)` but I suspect you meant to call `handler := handlers.GetArtworks(db)` (note the extra `s` at the end). If that is not your issue then please provide a [minimal example like this](https://go.dev/play/p/THwOyn8HfJI).

Comment: @CampbellPadgett please accept your submitted answer so other knows the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brits is correct: It was due to a misspelled handler

`handler := handlers.GetArtwork(db)`

should have been `handler := handlers.GetArtworks(db)`